# ERROR while getting interface

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

I have installed the latest version of aircrack-ng, but when i run this code,

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

I get this.

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0


Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
-e 
PID Name
463 avahi-daemon
475 avahi-daemon
683 NetworkManager
756 wpa_supplicant


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Broadcom    wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

Is there anyone who could help me get this problem solved please.

Comment: You might also have better luck with the open source driver rather than Broadcom wl.

Comment: I am running 14.04 LTS ubuntu. I am still very new to this so could you explain what you mean by open source please. I really need your help.

Comment: See [the wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) for instructions on installing the open source drivers. These drivers are in the kernel and generally better supported for things like this than the closed ones.

Comment: 14.04 is no longer supported here. The versions which are would be 16.04, 18.04, and 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

at 1º sorry for my english ;) write in you terminal

sudo su -------- its for meak you temporaly root

sudo service network-manager stop --------- now you stop NetworkManager, after rebot you pc network manager will be rebot auto

sudo service avahi-daemon stop ---------- for stop avahi, after rebot you pc avahi will rebot auto

airmon-ng check kill ----- kill process that could cause trouble, after rebot you pc these process will be rebot auto

whit ¨rebot auto¨ i mind, these programs/process will be UP/ON again. Sorry for my english again, and i hope thats is the answer for you problem ;))) Good Luck